# Custom URL for the Birdhouse app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, custom-url

I'd like to figure out the custom URL scheme for the Birdhouse iPhone app, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation.

Birdhouse is an app to store drafts for Twitter. I'd like to send it a string of text, and I know that it's possible:

- Birdhouse responds to the URL `birdhouse:///`
- The Twitter app sends drafts to Birdhouse if it's installed on your phone.

I've figured out the `birdhouse:///` part, but how do I send the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweeted the developer, and here's what he said:

> It's `birdhouse://?text=Hey`. Just make sure to URL escape the string after the "="!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like they broadcast the format for their URL's.  Your best bet might be to send their support team an email.  http://birdhouseapp.com/support.